# How can I add data (a python list) to a new column in an existing Excel file?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I want to add a new column on an existing Excel file. I was able to do this using the openpyxl library. This is the code I have:

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location)
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
worksheet.insert_cols(9)
workbook.save('/Users/jaime/Desktop/Try1.xlsx')
```

What the above code does is simply insert a new column before column 9. Now, I would like to add data to that column, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a list and I want to add that list in that new column I added. How can that be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself by doing the following:

In this first part of the code I'm simply creating an empty column in the existing Excel file at index 9.

```
y = 2
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location)
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
worksheet.insert_cols(9)
```

Now, in this part what I'm doing is adding the title to the new empty column created with above code and calling it 'New Column'.

```
cell_title = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=9)
cell_title.value = 'New Column'
```

Now, I'm iterating through the list that has the data that I want to add to the new column I created. This is where I use variable **y** to simply state that we will start adding values at row 2 because in row 1 we have the title of the column. So, we add the first value at row 2 and increment the variable until we iterate through the entire list.

```
for x in range(len(list)):
    cell_to_write = worksheet.cell(row=y, column=9)
    cell_to_write.value = list[x]
    y += 1
```

At last, save the workbook and the new column should be there with its corresponding data

```
workbook.save('/Users/username/Desktop/Try1.xlsx')
```